# Script: Writing mailbox SQL record based on system users

Tags: bash, shell-script, kali-linux

There's something wrong with this command or I'm not seeing my mistake. I also needed to exclude disabled users and users with UID over 500. This is the SQL command I need to use

```
INSERT INTO `mailbox` (`username`, `password`, `name`, `maildir`, `quota`, `local_part`, `domain`, `created`, `modified`, `active`) VALUES ('$username, '$pass', '', '$xxxx', 0, 'xxx', 'xxx', 'date --rfc-3339=date', 'date --rfc-3339=date', 1);"
```

[image: This is the script I wrote.]
[image: This is the output errors.]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: Please take some time to write a quality question, and in particular a meaningful title. e.g. I advise avoiding simple titles "as please help me". I could also swear this is a repost.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the backticks in the SQL are treated as command substitutions by the shell.  The shell would try to run backticked string as a command to replace that bit with the output of that particular command.

The shell does this because you `echo` the string with double quotes.

To solve this particular issue, escape each backtick as `` \` ``.

Ideally, you would pass the SQL as a single quoted string, but that would mean that the variables wouldn't be expanded.

You can also do it this way, which would be safer:

```
printf 'INSERT INTO `mailbox` (`username`, `password`, `name`, `maildir`, `quota`, `local_part`, `domain`, `created`, `modified`, `active`) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "", "%s", 0, "xxx", "xxx", "date --rfc-3339=date", "date --rfc-3339=date", 1);\n' "$username" "$pass" "$xxxx"
```

... assuming the particular database you are using can handle double quoted field data.

Comment: Kusalananda it did take the usernames and passwords and exclude the disabled users, but for each user it printed the whole `INSERT INTO mailbox ...` phrase as it is with only the usernames and passwords being filled out. What I forgot in the original question was to mention that I had written previously `echo "INSERT INTO ..." >> test.sql `

Comment: @JohnDoe Well, you can redirect the output of `printf` too...